# How to permute elements of a vector by another vector to obtain a matrix of permutations

Tags: matlab

I want to obtain all the possible permutations of one vector elements by another vector elements. For example one vector is A=[0 0 0 0] and another is B=[1 1]. I want to replace the elements of A by B to obtain all the permutations in a matrix like this [1 1 0 0; 1 0 1 0; 1 0 0 1; 0 1 1 0; 0 1 0 1; 0 0 1 1]. The length of real A is big and I should be able to choose the length of B_max and to obtain all the permutations of A with B=[1], [1 1], [1 1 1],..., B_max.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems fun, what've you got already?

Comment: There is no question here. Please describe what you've tried, how it's failed, and ask a *specific* question telling us what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, since `A` and `B` are always defined, respectively, as a vector of zeros and a vector of ones, this computation is much easier than you may think. The only constraints you should respect concerns `B`, which shoud not be empty and it's elements cannot be greater than or equal to the number of elements in `A`... because after that threshold `A` will become a vector of ones and calculating its permutations will be just a waste of CPU cycles.

Here is the core function of the script, which undertakes the creation of the unique permutations of `0` and `1` given the target vector `X`:

```
function p = uperms(X)
    n = numel(X);
    k = sum(X);
    c = nchoosek(1:n,k);
    m = size(c,1);

    p = zeros(m,n);
    p(repmat((1-m:0)',1,k) + m*c) = 1;
end
```

And here is the full code:

```
clear();
clc();

% Define the main parameter: the number of elements in A...
A_len = 4;

% Compute the elements of B accordingly...
B_len = A_len - 1;
B_seq = 1:B_len;

% Compute the possible mixtures of A and B...
X = tril(ones(A_len));
X = X(B_seq,:);

% Compute the unique permutations...
p = [];

for i = B_seq
    p = [p; uperms(X(i,:).')];
end
```

Output for `A_len = 4`:

```
p =
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1
     1     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0
     1     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0
     0     1     0     1
     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0
     1     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If we want to do the same with a B which contains other numbers like -2 or if A contains other numbers like 4 and B contains 2, is it possible to obtain p as the previous case? Thank you.

Comment: No, things can be very different. But after all, if you post sample data in your question, I build an answer around it.

Comment: Consider A=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] and B1=c, B2=[c c], B3=[c c c] and B4=[c c c c] where c=+1, -1, +2, -2. I need to obtain all the permutations of A by B's. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, but this has nothing to do with your original question and I'm not a code writing service.

Comment: This is just a sample data of my original question.